# SonarQube doesn't add JavaScript coverage

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a multi module maven project that has Java and JavaScript sub projects.
For SonarQube analysis we have added configuration to JavaScript module.

```
<sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
<sonar.exclusions>src/test/**/*, src/**/resources/simple/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>src/**/resources/simple/**/*, src/registerServiceWorker.js</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
<sonar.projectBaseDir>.</sonar.projectBaseDir>
<sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin>lcov</sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>opui-client/target/surefire-reports</sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>
<sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>coverage/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
<sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
```

SonarQube shows the analysis logs.

```
Analysing [C:\Users\mzafar\opui-19dec\path\to\file\coverage\lcov.info]
[WARNING] Problem during processing LCOV report: can't save DA data for line 1491 (Line with number 1491 doesn't belong to file src/modules/core/NagraGrid.js).
```

Part of lcov.info is like this:

```
SF:C:\Users\mzafar\path\to\js\code\src\modules\core\search\opuiSearch\AdvancedSearchOptionsPopup.js
FN:89,(anonymous_0)
FN:100,(anonymous_1)
FN:113,(anonymous_2)
FN:119,(anonymous_3)
FN:125,(anonymous_4)
FN:129,(anonymous_5)
FN:167,(anonymous_6)
FN:179,(anonymous_7)
FN:188,(anonymous_8)
FN:197,(anonymous_9)
FN:200,(anonymous_10)
FN:209,(anonymous_11)
FNF:12
FNH:10
FNDA:8,(anonymous_0)
FNDA:4,(anonymous_1)
FNDA:1,(anonymous_2)
FNDA:1,(anonymous_3)
FNDA:1,(anonymous_4)
FNDA:26,(anonymous_5)
FNDA:26,(anonymous_6)
FNDA:0,(anonymous_7)
FNDA:26,(anonymous_8)
FNDA:1,(anonymous_9)
FNDA:1,(anonymous_10)
FNDA:0,(anonymous_11)
DA:10,3
DA:82,3
DA:90,8
DA:91,8
DA:101,4
DA:102,4
DA:114,1
DA:120,1
DA:121,1
DA:126,1
DA:130,26
DA:131,0
DA:134,26
DA:136,2
DA:148,2
DA:160,22
DA:168,26
DA:180,0
DA:189,26
DA:198,1
DA:201,1
DA:210,0
DA:211,0
LF:23
LH:19
BRDA:101,0,0,4
BRDA:101,0,1,0
BRDA:120,1,0,1
BRDA:120,1,1,0
BRDA:130,2,0,0
BRDA:130,2,1,26
BRDA:130,3,0,26
BRDA:130,3,1,0
BRDA:134,4,0,2
BRDA:134,4,1,2
BRDA:134,4,2,22
BRDA:195,5,0,11
BRDA:195,5,1,15
BRDA:232,6,0,25
BRDA:232,6,1,1
BRDA:247,7,0,0
BRDA:247,7,1,26
BRDA:265,8,0,0
BRDA:265,8,1,26
BRDA:275,9,0,26
BRDA:275,9,1,0
BRDA:276,10,0,26
BRDA:276,10,1,0
BRF:23
BRH:15
end_of_record
```

But still JavaScript files coverage is 0. We are using SonarQube 6.7. Can someone help me if some configuration is wrong?

Comment: How many lines are there in src/modules/core/NagraGrid.js? Was lcov.info updated since the last modification of NagraGrid.js?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Since it is part of the build, it must be updated everyday. But i wonder lcov.info refers to some old files too that have been removed. NagraGrid.js has 1490 lines of code. We are using jest for testing with --coverage option for coverage.

Comment: If NagraGrid.js has 1490 lines and lcov.info refers to code on line 1491, then you have a problem with your lcov.info. Maybe it's not updated before the SonarQube analysis or on the same version of the analysed code.

Comment: @Pierre-Yves I used <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath> and coverage is appearing alongwith the files but is the property <sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath> correct because I am not seeing the Javascript unit test files, only Java test files?

Comment: Does that mean that you fixed your original issue? If so, you should add an answer here. I suggest to open a new question about the import of test results: `sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the latest sonar property

```
<sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>path/to/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>
```

And this solved the issue for me.